# making tree with unordered_map

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map

I want to use Node class as value in `unordered_map`, but when I tried to compile, I encountered the same problem as [Using unordered_map with custom value object in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25173911/using-unordered-map-with-custom-value-object-in-c)
In the answer for the above question, only how to use pointer to Node was mentioned.

Interestingly `map<Key,Node>` compiles with no error. But I don't want to use `map` because `map` use red-black tree which has time complexity of O(log(n)), on the other hand, `unordered_map` seems to take constant time.

Below is Node class and a related struct.

```
struct Bundle{
    double prob;
    vector<int> type;
};

typedef struct Bundle Bundle;
class Node {
    public:
        unordered_map<unsigned, Bundle> bundle;
        unordered_map<unsigned, Node> childs;
    private:
        //private method here
};
```

Comment: What kind of type is Node?

Comment: sorry i should have specified the problem in more detail. I will edit soon.

Comment: My first guess at your problem is that Node cannot be copied. unordered_map is implemented as a hash table, but sometimes the hash table gets resized, and the elements need to be re-hashed and copied/moved to their new location. If node cannot be copied or moved, you can't use it as a value type in an unordered_map. You could use Node* or unique_ptr<Node> instead, if you wanted.

Comment: @Charlie I see. If I use Node* or unique_ptr<Node>, I guess I have to manually clear all the children node whereas map does not require me to do so.

Comment: @Charlie It might be a stupid question,but why is it impossible to copy/move Node?

Comment: @HitoshiOtsuki, no, if you use `unique_ptr<Node>` you do **not** need to manually do anything, the `unique_ptr` destructor will run the `Node` destructor

Comment: @JonathanWakely What happens if `childs` does not have some key and I want to attach new node to the key? Do I have to use something like `new` to allocate memory manually?

Comment: Yes, but you don't need to free it manually afterwards

Comment: @HitoshiOtsuki My guess about copyability was from before you posted more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Node {
    public:
        unordered_map<unsigned, Bundle> bundle;
        unordered_map<unsigned, Node> childs;
```

At this point the `Node` type is not yet complete, because you're still defining it.

Instantiating most standard library templates (such as `unordered_map`) with an incomplete type is undefined behaviour. It *might* work with some compilers, but it might not. The reason is that the template might need to know things like `sizeof(Node)` and whether `Node` is nothrow-copy-constructible, and it can't know those things for an incomplete type.

I'm guessing you're using GCC, which supports incomplete types in `std::map` (as a non-standard extension) but not `std::unordered_map`. Your options are to use a different container, or to use a container of different types (e.g. `unordered_map<unsigned, unique_ptr<Node>>`)

Answer (score 0):

To add to what Jonathan Wakely said, you can also use a `std::unique_ptr` to the `std::unordered_map` itself, as such:

```cpp
class Node {
    public:
        unordered_map<unsigned, Bundle> bundle;
        const unique_ptr<unordered_map<unsigned, Node>> childs;
        Node() : childs(make_unique<unordered_map<unsigned, Node>>) { }
```

This is marked `const` as so unique pointer itself cannot be cleared, changed or invalidated (could be non-const also) and making sure it's created during the object construction. You'd access childs as `(*node.childs)[10]`, for example.